# Using windowManager parameters to have keyboard

Tags: android, flags, window-managers

I am using these parameters to show an image on the screen. (this is running on a service cause of that i am using windowmanager instead of usual way- the image comes and goes continuesly)

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                 WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                 WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
                    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT

);
```

The Point is when I use `FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE` it allows user's touch go through the Picture, Which is fine and it is what I want. but when there is a need for text entry the keyboard keeps disappering (I want it to be there so I am able to input text even though the Picture is overlapping). this works for buttons and other input but the the keybord vanishes. How can I keep both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing `WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE` to  `WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY` solved the problem.

Comment: WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY is deprecated. Alternative is TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY